# Why is my USB Ethernet Card not working in Ubuntu 14.04 Server?

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, usb, ethernet

I've got a laptop which I'm trying to set up as a server (a rebadged Uniwill 223ii0), but it has an ethernet port which is dodgy (sometimes works, sometimes doesn't).

I bought a [£20 usb ethernet card](http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/usb-20-to-ethernet-adapter-a31gy) which worked out of the box when the laptop was running Windows 7, and worked during the server install, but not once the server was standing on its own two feet, as it tries to get network configuration on boot, then waits another minute before giving up and completing the boot.

Once logged in, using `sudo ifup eth2` yields that it is already configured, so bringing the adapter down and up yields with a long `DHCPDISCOVER` sequence which yields that "the network is down".

I am using the adapter on my Windows 7 machine right now to write this, and the same cable in the dodgy port on the laptop is working, for now

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Huh, looks like I found a bug with the way 14.04 is installed.

It turns out that whilst my USB card was eth2 on install, it got reassigned eth1 afterward, and the system tried to connect on eth2 (whatever eth2 may be, unless the onboard modem or wireless card counts as an ethernet interface).

Replacing eth2 with eth1 in `/etc/network/interfaces` and bringing up the adapter with `sudo ifup eth1` solved this for me

Answer (score 0):

With logical computer counting, we start at 0 as the first point of contact and not 1;  so then we use 1 for the 2nd, 2 for the 3rd, and so on. So logically if `eth0` is the 1st Ethernet port, then `eth1` would logically have to be the second Ethernet port, eth2 the 3rd..... So that explains why eth2 was not working and why `eth1` is working since you have 2 ports, eth0 the dodgy built-in port and eth1 the USB Ethernet port. Add yet another USB Ethernet adapter and `eth2` should work seamlessly on that 3rd port, when configured properly to do so, of course.

A great trick in Terminal to see ALL networking ports is with this simple command and flag:

```
ifconfig -a
```

I had similar issues with Ubuntu Server and specifically with how it named its ports. I found for some reason the build I used wasn't using eth it was using `p2p1`?. With me renaming the `/etc/network/interfaces` file's listed interfaces I was able to get it working using eth0 and not `p2p1`. That was found it out simply by calling the `ifconfig -a` command, emphasizing its usefulness.